# Resetting a DSL 2wire gateway Model 2701HG-S

Tags: wireless-networking

Setting up wifi for a friend who doesn't know what the password on the router was set to. It's a 2wire gateway Model 2701HG-S.

I need to reset it, but want to know if there are any settings I can get out of it or need to put back in for the thing to work. Like MAC address cloning or whatever.

Thoughts? Default passwords?

Answer (score 0):

No way to know!

Some ISPs require username/password for connections, others don't.

As 2wire routers (at least in the UK) are only supplied by ISPs, they are usually pre configured with default settings that allow connections, so unless this was moved from somewhere else, you can be pretty confident that after a reset, it should work straight away.

Just remember, Wireless security/password will be reset, so connect in to it via wire to make changes after you have reset.

Answer (score 0):

Alot of the 2wire routers have a hidden admin menu. Try http://IP_ADDRESS/mdc and then use the password "2wire" to get in to the advanced config. This at least works with the 2700hgv routers, not sure about the 2700-s though.